# What plugin should I use for a basic user signup/login system

Tags: plugins, user-registration

I need to present a user signup/login system on the front end of my site.

My requirements are pretty straight forward:

- I don't want the user to ever wind up in the WP admin panel.
- A signed up user will have access to one additional page
- I want to keep track of email addresses from these users
- I would like to provide a forgot my password link.
- The users only need to provide an email and password to sign up

Any ideas? plugin or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

You can try out Profile Builder: http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/

The free version will solve almost all your problems. As for member access try out Members: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

These two plugins should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the membership plugin. I'm using that on wpLifeGuard and it's a fantastic plugin.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership

And you can use the Login Redirect plugin to keep users from seeing the WP backend.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/login-redirect

You could probably use the free login redirect plugin and standard WordPress users with private pages to accomplish what you're wanting - unless they're paid accounts. If they're paid accounts then you'll likely have to use the Membership plugin or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Another good plugin for member management is [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).

You can assign Content Permissions to only allow a certain role to access the post/page. There is the benefit of it being free but it will not automatically handle paid subscriptions if that is what you are looking for.

WordPress already natively handles some of the functions that you are looking for.

- Lost Password
- Registration
- You can view e-mail addresses in your Admin Panel

And like brianpurkiss said you can use a login redirect plugin to prevent users from seeing their admin panel. I would suggest [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/).